# How ^y is represented in vim editor?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

What keys should be used to enter ^y in the vim editor.
For example,

```
hello ^m
Welcome ^m
^y^m
```

Here ^y^m is used to separate paragraphs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can type any literal character with `<ctrl-v><character>`. Thus, to type `^y` you can type `<ctrl-v><ctrl-y>`.

---

As pointed out by @mMontu in the comments, it is possible that `<ctrl-v>` is mapped to something else, e.g. on Windows if `$VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim` is loaded. One can check if there is any custom mappings with [`:map <c-v>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq%2d20%2e1).

Comment: It is possible that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>is [`mapped to something else`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq%2d20%2e1)(for example, `$VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim` maps it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>).